# Not sure how to add opencv library to CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, ros

I'm using Apple, CMake 2.8.1 in order to build my project on Ubuntu 10.04:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /home/user/workspace)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()
find_package(OpenCV 2) 

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

rosbuild_add_executable (RosPub src/paste.cpp)
target_link_libraries (RosPub openni_driver usb-1.0 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I need to add OpenCV libraries on my project. I have added them but I can't still get my code to work. It keeps outputting this error:

> struct MyOpenNIExample::ImgContext’ has no member named ‘image’

There are a few of them:

After I added `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` to the CMakeLists.txt, I got this error:

```
Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindOpenCV.cmake or set OpenCV_DIR  
 to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for OpenCV.  
 The file will have one of the following names:
         OpenCVConfig.cmake
         opencv-config.cmake
```

Since I need:

```cpp
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
```

I added

```bash
find_package(OpenCV 2), 
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /home/user/workspace)
```

and

```bash
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries (RosPub openni_driver usb-1.0 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp" 
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
```

the include files above are included in the vision_opencv in ROS. so to include it, add the opencv dependency in the manifest file.

That would help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get `FindOpenCV.cmake` from above link and put it anywhere on your computer.
2. After `cmake_minimum_required` add line `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})` [`${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}` denotes the path to folder where you put FindOpenCV.cmake])
3. Add `find_package(OpenCV)` to your CMakeLists.txt
4. On this step you can check for OpenCV_FOUND and other OpenCV variables in your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I mean link from @spraff answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. is add line something like that : set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} [/media/Data/workspace/Lakshmen])

Comment: shld i include find_package[OpenCV required] btw, the header file i am trying to include is #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

Comment: i have this error: OpenCV was not found. Please specify OpenCV directory using OpenCV_DIR env. variable

Comment: Great. Then try to specify OpenCV_DIR environment variable. For linux it can be done right from command line - "OpenCV_DIR=[path to installed OpenCV] cmake [path to your CMakeLists.txt]"

Comment: is it the same for <opencv2/opencv.hpp> too?

Comment: Don't be sorry. Just read cmake documentation. FindOpenCV.cmake looks for "${OpenCV_DIR}/OpenCVConfig.cmake" file which just autogenerated information where the includes and libs can be found. In my case (Fedora 14 i686) opencv-devel package must be installed and OpenCVConfig.cmake is resides in /usr/lib/cmake/opencv folder. So in my case OpenCV_DIR=/usr/lib/cmake/opencv

Comment: Sorry it is a package in ROS. i need not add OPENCV lib... It was my mistake. Sorry. Anyway, thanks for helping.